# How to delete roles using discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to create a command that deletes a specified role when you type it in. But it doesn't work. I've searched up solutions but only found tutorials in async, and I am using rewrite. Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def delrole(ctx, *, name):
    await ctx.guild.remove_roles(name)
    await ctx.send(f"Succesfully deleted the {name} role")
```

Answer (score 2):

First, get the role using one of discord.py's utility functions (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get):

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=name)
```

Then delete the role (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.delete):

```py
await role.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably like this

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "role_name")
await bot.delete_role(ctx.guild, role)
await bot.send(f"Succesfully deleted the {role.name} role")
```

Answer (score 1):

`remove_role` is for removing roles from a **Member**.

To delete a role you need to use `delete_role`

An example as follows:

```py
guild = ctx.guild
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "role's name")
await client.delete_role(guild, role)
```